# monthly slope coefficient regressing first column with rest of the column

Tags: r, linear-regression

I like to regress the first column means market return (as y) with rest of the columns (as X) and create a data frame with the list of monthly slope coefficients. My data frame is like this

```
Date    Marker return   AFARAK GROUP PLC    AFFECTO OYJ
1/3/2007    -0.45               0.00           0.85
1/4/2007    -0.92               2.47          -0.85
1/5/2007    -1.98               3.98          -1.14
```

The expected output of slope coefficient data frame is like this

```
Date    AFARAK GROUP PLC    AFFECTO OYJ
Jan-07      1                   0.5
Feb-07      2                   1.5
Mar-07      2                   1
Apr-07      3                   2
```

Could someone help me in this regard?

Comment: what have you tried so far?  You can do this with tidyverse, but I would do it by (1) defining a month column (`factor(format(Date,"%b-%Y"))`) and (2) using `nlme::lmList`

Comment: I tried to find covariance with this formula : library(zoo)
DF2<-aggregate(DF, as.yearmon, function(x) cov(x,DF[index(x),"Mkt.Return"]))
Later I thought that I will devide it by market variecne to calculate slopes. However this formula also not working.